# jQuery: Split <td> from <tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string containing `<tr>`s and `<td>`s. I want to split the data from the `<td>`s into an array. So that this:

```
<tr>
 <td>Test</td>
 <td>Hey</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Test2</td>
 <td>Hey2</td>
</tr>
```

Becomes:

```
array[0] = { test, hey }
array[1] = { test2, hey2 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var originalString = "<tr><td>Test</td><td>Hey</td></tr><tr><td>Test2</td><td>Hey2</td></tr>";
var targetArray = [];

$(originalString) /*.find("tr")*/ .each(function(index, tr) {
  targetArray[index] = $("td", tr).map(function(index, td) {return $(td).text();});
});
```

Comment: It looks really neat and should work like this, but it doesn't run out of the box on my Firebug console (array stays empty).

Comment: Thanks because i didn't test it :-) I'm deleting the `find("tr")`, because `$(originalString)` is already a set of the two `tr` elements. You would need the `find("tr")`, if then original string contained more, for example, a whole table.

Comment: Arg. I think jQuery's documentation of `map` is wrong. It says "jQuery.map( array, callback(elementOfArray, indexInArray) )" however the parameters of the callback function are swapped.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either... im getting this in Chrome: Object 0 has no method 'text'

Comment: this is the correct answer except that .text() has to be replaced with .html()

Answer (score 1):

jQuery? For what?

```
var array = [];
var strArray = "Test Hey Test2 Hey2".split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i += 2) {
   array[i] = [strArray[i], strArray[i + 1]];
}
```

#### Edit (according to your edit)

```
var array = new Array();
$("tr").each(function() {
    array.push([ $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(), $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text() ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Here's a much shorter JQuery version of the below (*I tested on jQuery 1.4.2*):

```
function split(s) {
    return $.map(s.split('<tr>').slice(1), function(i) {
        return [$.map(i.split('<td>').slice(1), function(i) {
            return i.split('</td>')[0]
        })]
    })
}
var L = split('<tr><td>Test</td><td>Hey</td><tr><td>Test2</td><td>Hey2</td></tr>');
```

Here's the previous raw JavaScript version which is still probably faster than the above:

```
function split(s) {
    var L = s.split('<tr>');
    var rtn = [];
    for (var x=1; x<L.length; x++) {
         var iL = L[x].split('<td>')
         iRtn = []
         for (var y=1; y<iL.length; y++) {
             iRtn.push(iL[y].split('</td>')[0]);
         }
         rtn.push(iRtn)
    }
    return rtn;
}
var L = split('<tr><td>Test</td><td>Hey</td><tr><td>Test2</td><td>Hey2</td></tr>');
```

I've tested it to work on basic strings with tables in them, but it doesn't unescape e.g. `&nbsp;` etc and it obviously won't handle nested tables. Should be faster using only string split methods, but I'm sure it can be done shorter with JQuery `$(x).map`. It also requires the table `<tr>` and `<td>`'s to be lowercased as it's written.